# PrimeNG Angular 6 turbotable with separate search field throws error

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I am trying to use a global "search" filter box for a PrimeNG turbotable, as in [their example](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/filter), except putting the global search field outside the table (they have their inside the table in a `caption`, but my design calls for a toolbar above the table.

It should work, but I keep getting the error on compile

`Property 'filterGlobal' does not exist on type 'DataTable'.`

and the app won't run.  I see nothing in their example about `filterGlobal`. At this point, I am stumped. It feels like something needs to be declared or imported somewhere, but I have no idea.

My table html:

```
<div class="toolbar">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <input type="text"
               placeholder="Search"
               (input)="dt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')">
    </form>
</div>
<span *ngIf="people$ | async as people">
  <p-table #dt 
        [value]="people"
        [paginator]="true"
        [rows]="10" 
        [totalRecords]="people?.length"
        [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,20,30,50]" 
        [globalFilterFields]="['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'age', 'country']"
        >
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of cols">{{col.header}}</th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body"
              let-rowData
              let-columns="cols">
    <tr>
      <td *ngFor="let col of cols">{{rowData[col.field]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
</span>
```

And in my Typescript:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MockDataService } from '../../shared/services/mock-data.service';
import { DataTable } from 'primeng/primeng';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-turbotable-deluxe',
  templateUrl: './turbotable-deluxe.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class TurbotableDeluxeComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('dt')
  dt: DataTable;

  people$;
  cols;

  constructor(private mockdata: MockDataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.people$ = this.mockdata.get('people_100.json');

    this.cols = [
      { field: 'first_name', header: 'First Name' },
      { field: 'last_name', header: 'Last Name' },
      { field: 'age', header: 'Age' },
      { field: 'email', header: 'Email' },
      { field: 'country', header: 'Country' }
    ];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The right class for p-table is "Table".
I found it in the source code of primeNg.

Comment: What do you mean by "right class"?  The documentation clearly shows adding a table with `<p-table>` tags.  A `<table>` tag would just add a normal HML table.

Comment: I mean " @ViewChild('dt')
  dt: DataTable;" is wrong. It should be "... dt : Table;" or "any" If you want. In this way the compiler works.

Comment: `dt: Table` does not work, as there's no typing for `Table`.  I also can't find anything named "Table" in `/primeng/primeng` to import.  "any" does work, though.